How do I upload images in Wagtail with clean resolution?
When I upload an image with a resolution of 96 dpi in Wagtail, the image quality looks very coarse on the HP.
What solutions do you have for this issue?
The image is the SDG logo image, downloaded from the official SDG website.

Maybe you should start by checking on the image quality settings, https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/images.html#image-quality

If perhaps the DPI is somehow the issue, maybe try and convert it to 72 DPI in an image editor first.

It helps to know the format and pixel dimensions of the image file its "dpi" value tells us almost nothing about it (except for the dpi resolution it might print on some systems).

DPI is not important here. Look out for the overall resolution of the image and its compression rate in the template.
You should use the {% image %} or {% picture %} template tags to implement an image in your website template, see documentation. To use the original file, set the resizing method to "original":
{% image page.logo original %}

Or create a rendition with the resolution and compression rate (quality) of your choice:
{% image page.logo width-640 jpegquality-100 %}

The DPI (dots per inch) will depend on the size and resolution of the user’s screen. Use the {% picture %} tag to define responsive images with multiple renditions for different viewports (small, large, retina, etc.).
